# How to delay processing reasonably in Java EE context?

Tags: java, sleep, java-ee-5

Within a Java EE 5 environment I have the problem to ensure the existence of some data written by another part before continue processing my own data.

Historically (J2EE time), it was done by putting the data object to be processed into an internal JMS queue after waiting for e.g. 500ms via Thread.sleep.

But this does not feel like the best way to handle that problem, so I have 2 questions:

1. Is there any problem with using the sleep method within an Java EE context?
2. What is a reasonable solution to delaying some processing within an Java EE 5 application?

---

**Edit:**

I should have mentioned, that my processing takes place while handling objects from a JMS queue via an MDB.

And it may be the case, that the data for which I'm waiting never shows up, so there must be some sort of timeout, after which I can do some special processing with my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @dkaustubh about timers and avoiding threads manipulation in JavaEE.

Another possibility is to use JMS queue with delayed delivery. Although it is not a part of JavaEE API, most of messaging systems vendors supports it. [check here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/sending-delayed-jms-messages).

Comment: That's a very good hint - the applications runs within a JBoss 5.1, so [this JBoss forum question](https://community.jboss.org/message/559414), one has to set `JMS_JBOSS_SCHEDULED_DELIVERY_PROP_NAME`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use EJB TimerService feature. Using threads in a managed environment should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

I think, its possible with some advanced Threading approach. More than thinking on manual synchronizations and thread management, you can always use the `Java Concurrent` package.

[Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) can be one of the ways to do this. Please refer to Java Concurrent package.

Answer (score -1):

Use notifications and `Object#wait()` / `Object#notifyAll()`
i.e. Multithreaded, the producer notifies the consumer.

Comment: Are you sure this can be safely done within a Java EE application? My processing occurs from a JMS queue, so I fear I will disturb the whole process by implementing my own synchronisation mechanisms here. Besides, I additionally need a timeout in case the information from the 1st source is not available. (I added that to my question.)

Comment: Well, wait() can time out (use Object#wait(long timeout))... Not sure about the synchronisation. There are also a lot of helper classes in the JRE which to the synchronisation for you.

Comment: Ok, but again, the application runs within a Java EE container, so I'd like to know whether or not I can use these mechanisms at all?

Comment: @Geziefer theoretically, yes. Which components are snychronising on each other anyways? For Beans there is the Synchronisation mechanic...
Maybe [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/ejb/SessionSynchronization.html) is applicable?

Comment: @AlexR SessionSynchronization is only applicable to handle transactions/ two-phase commit. Thread manipulation is forbidden by JavaEE spec, as container responsibility is to manage pool of threads/bean instances.